# Unknown function addElement. Check spelling apex salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i created a visualforce page in which there is a code segment

```
<apex:column ><apex:commandButton value="{!if(item.i == size-1,'Add','Delete')}" action="{!if(size == 1,addElement(),removeElement())}"></apex:commandButton></apex:column>
```

i created a custom controller containing function

```
public PageReference addElement(){

return null;

}
public PageReference removeElement(){

return null;

}
```

but when i try to save the visualforce page it is giving me error

```
Error: Unknown function addElement. Check spelling
```

can any one please tell me how to use if structure in action attribute so that it will properly work

Comment: Are you trying to call the addElement()/removeElement() method present in the controller? If yes then you dont need to specify the round brackets in the action attribute. It should simply be action="{!IF(size == 1, addElement, removeElement}"

Comment: i tried that also but it will give me error unknown property addElement after that i tried addElement() .please check it by yourself

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
<apex:commandButton value="{!if(item.i == size-1,'Add','Delete')}" action="{!addElement}" rendered="{!size == 1}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="{!if(item.i == size-1,'Add','Delete')}" action="{!removeElement}" rendered="{!NOT(size == 1)}"/>
```